# Azure DevOps: Is it possible to hide specific Epics from a group of Users

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps, we have created Epics to group features together.

Now we would like to make some of them visible to a specific group of users. They would be in read-only mode.

How can it be done ?  We know it is possible to create rules to make some fields read-only, but it goes as far as that. Also, is it possible to make all fields read-only instead of going through each of them.

But most importantly how can we hide all epics but these specific ones for that group of users ?

Comment: Work item access is controlled by area path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements should be able to be achieved through the area settings.

Project Settings -> Team configuration -> Areas-> Security
[image]

Put the Epics you want only some people to see under an Area, then put some people you don’t want to see these epics into a group, and set "View work items in this node" to Deny . Then users in this group will not see these epics.
[image]
As for setting some epics as read-only, please create a new Area and set "Edit work items in this node" in the above figure to Deny to prevent users in this group from modifying these epics.